# change default language slug

Tags: wordpress, wpml

Now I am using WPML language Wordpress plugin.

**Requirement**

> https://swissehkwp.saltandfuessel.com.au/zh-hans/health-happiness-blog/

Now I want to access above page like below

> https://swissehkwp.saltandfuessel.com.au/zh-hk/health-happiness-blog/

In simple way I need "**zh-hk**" instead of "**zh-hans**"  (Chinese language)

Answer (score 0):

There are no way to change existing language code slug. It's only possible with change direct from database. This may be dangerous!

To change the language code slug:

- Create a new custom language and set the code there.

=> Go to WPML=> Languages , "Site Languages" , and click on Edit Languages, from there add language.

ex. create your custom language set the slug as **zh-hk** instead of **zh-hans**